# Javascript animationend event listener acting differently on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, dom-events

I'm trying to make a slider with translade3d and scale animation.

I'm adding an event listener to animationend event with vendor prefixes, to make slides appear and disapear.

It works great on Chrome, Safari and Opera, but it fails in Firefox. It seems to be triggering the event for all slides when the first slide triggers animationend.

Here is the Javascript :

```
function slideCallBack(selector,i,list){

            var slide = this;
            slide.selector = selector;
            slide.nextSlide = list[i+1];

            if ( i === list.length-1 ) {
                slide.nextSlide = list[0];
            }

            slide.selector.style.display = "none";

            if ( typeof(slide.nextSlide) !== 'undefined' ) {
            slide.nextSlide.style.display = "block";
            slide.nextSlide.className = slide.nextSlide.className + " slide-effect-left";   
            }

    }


    function setUpSlider(classname){

        this.elementList = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
        var sliderConfig = this;


            for (var i=0;i<sliderConfig.elementList.length;++i) {
            PrefixedEvent(sliderConfig.elementList[i], "AnimationEnd", i, sliderConfig.elementList);
            }   

        sliderConfig.elementList[0].style.display = "block";        

    }

    var pfx = ["webkit", "MS", "o", "", "moz"];
    function PrefixedEvent(element, type, iterator, list) {
                for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
                    if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
                    element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, function() { slideCallBack(element,iterator,list) }, false);
                }
    }

setUpSlider('slide');
```

Here are the Keyframes :

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 60px, 0px) scale(2,2);
        transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0px) scale(2,2);
    }
    15% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(30%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
        transform: translate3d(30%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(70%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
        transform: translate3d(70%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
        }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150%, -200%, 500px) scale(2,2);
        transform:translate3d(150%, -200%, 500px) scale(2,2);
        }
}



@keyframes slideLeft {
   0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 60px, 0px) scale(2,2);
        transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0px) scale(2,2);
    }
    15% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(30%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
        transform: translate3d(30%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(70%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
        transform: translate3d(70%, 30px, 0px) scale(1,1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150%, -200%, 500px) scale(2,2);
        transform:translate3d(150%, -200%, 500px) scale(2,2);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why Firefox does not handle it the same way ?

Comment: If your edit got it working, you should post it as an answer and remove the answer from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, placed the keyframes in a specific class and removed the class from current slide when animationend is triggered, and added that class to next slide. Works like a charm on all mordern browser.

here is the callback adjusted:

```
function slideCallBack(selector,i,list){

        var slide = this;
        slide.selector = selector;
        slide.nextSlide = list[i+1];

        if ( i === list.length-1 ) {
            slide.nextSlide = list[0];
        }
        slide.selector.className = 'cold-md-4 slide';
        slide.selector.style.display = "none";

        slide.nextSlide.style.display = "block";
        slide.nextSlide.className = slide.nextSlide.className + " slide-effect-left";   
}
```